# How to update dependencies?

Tags: flutter

Error:

```
The plugins `admob_flutter, flutter_ringtone_player` use a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if these plugins support the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing them since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
```

I tried the command  `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions` and  `flutter pub upgrade admob_flutter` , but nothing changed

Comment: A flutter 2.5 issue. Because of it I downgrade for the moment

Comment: How do I find out which version was used in the project?

Comment: Version of flutter you mean? with the command flutter --version